# (How) can I use System.import in babel along with require.js?

Tags: babeljs, systemjs, es6-module-loader

I'm playing a little bit with the new *ES6* functionalities and Babel. I'm successfully using the modules export/import functionalities by means of *require.js* (transpiling into *AMD*), but the experimental *module loader* doesn't want to work. Here is my code and configurations:

extract of `front-app/tst.js`

```
import {tstimp as functocall} from "front-app/tstimp.js";

...

/**
 * LOADING MODULES DYNAMICALLY
 */
System.import('front-app/tst_dyn_mod')
    .then(some_module => {
        console('using the module!');
        some_module.sayHello();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error!');
        console.log(error);
    });
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

and the scripts I import are these ones, in that order:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
        <script data-main="front-app/tst" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately what I get is the following error by using firefox:

```
error! tst.js:695:9
Error: a is undefined
    Error loading http://localhost/es6r1/front-app/tst_dyn_mod
```

what's that `a`? Am I missing something? Keep in mind my code is transpiled into AMD, but `System` is supposed to stay there in the transpiled code (and it IS there). The polyfill should do the dirty job, right?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully get the thing working on Babel 6 with a slighlty different config (*babel-node* cli & thus *commonjs*) thanks to this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-system-import (`npm install babel-plugin-system-import-transformer`). Here's a excerpt of my *.babelrc*:

```
…
"plugins": [
  "system-import-transformer",
  {
    "modules": "common"
  }
]
…
```

Setting `amd` instead of common like indicated in the documentation should do the trick for you.

Only limitation of this tiny plugin, you should get a plain string module name like `System.import("plainString")` and not a computed one (nor string concatenation with `+`, nor new ES6 [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and neither variable name). It seemds linked to [that line of code](https://github.com/thgreasi/babel-plugin-system-import-transformer/blob/master/index.js#L252).

I will try to PR a fix on that limitation if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this, https://github.com/thgreasi/babel-plugin-system-import-transformer has support for non string parameters. Just make sure not to use the updated alias package.